# Ruby on Rails "Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=links"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller

I want to have a page that displays links to other websites in my project. I created links.html.erb in my customers views but when I try access the page I get this error.

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CustomersController#show`

`Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=links`

Customers Controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /customers
  # GET /customers.json
  def index
    @customers = Customer.all
    @q = Tour.search(params[:q])
    @tours = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per(5)
    @q.build_condition if @q.conditions.empty?
    @q.build_sort if @q.sorts.empty?
  end

  def links
  end

  # GET /customers/1
  # GET /customers/1.json
  def show
    @customers = Customer.all
  end

  def welcome
  end

  # GET /customers/new
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
  end

  # GET /customers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /customers
  # POST /customers.json
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /customers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /customers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.update(customer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /customers/1
  # DELETE /customers/1.json
  def destroy
    @customer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to customers_url, notice: 'Customer record successfully deleted' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_customer
      @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :address, :telephone_no, :ticket_number)
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  resources :customers
  resources :tours
  devise_for :users


  root 'customers#welcome'
```

In view:

```
<% if current_user.customer? %>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<%= link_to image_tag("image1.jpg", size: "300x300"), {:controller => 'customers', :action => "links" } %>

<h3>Links</H3>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Anyone help with what is wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant view page code? also the routes

Comment: Also, can you indicate which line is triggering the error?

Comment: I think there is problem on your view.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `get 'links' => 'customers#links', as: :link` to the routes.rb and update your link as:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("image1.jpg", size: "300x300"), link_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of an expansion on Ganesh's answer.

When you do this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("image1.jpg", size: "300x300"), {:controller => 'customers', :action => "links" } %>
```

You're creating a url to:

```
customers/links
```

In your routes, the first match for `customers/links` is `customers/:id` which routes to `customers/show` with `params[:id] = 'links'`. See the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) if you don't understand why this is true. That's why you're getting the error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CustomersController#show
>
> Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=links

As Ganesh correctly points out, you can coerce the routes exactly as he says. To me, it is a little smelly to put this links page in the CustomerController and to coerce the routes. But, that's really a design decision based on the problem(s) you're trying to solve.

Comment: This is great explanation :) Thanks @jvillian